# Is there a way/hint to extract dictionary in between in a given condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text-extraction

Given a dictionary:

```
{0: 'Hello', 1: 'Bob', 2: '!', 3: 'Hello', 4: 'Bob', 5: '?', 6: 'Hello', 7: 'Bob', 8: '!', 9: 'Hello', 10: 'Jane', 11: '!', 12: 'Hello', 13: 'Rob', 14: '?'}
```

I wanted to extract these texts, inclusively, in between the pairs 'Hello' and '!' and ignore pairs 'Hello' and '?' but I am currently stuck. I just need a nudge in the right direction will do.

So far I have attempted to slice them and got the following result:

```
{0: 'Hello', 2: '!', 3: 'Hello', 5: '?', 6: 'Hello', 8: '!', 9: 'Hello', 11: '!', 12: 'Hello', 14: '?'}
```

but now I have no clue how to pair the values. For example pairs 0,2 then pairs 7,8 then finally 9,11.

Here is the method I made

```
def split(array):
    print(array)
    names = {'Hello','?','!'}
    lst = {key:value for key, value in array.items() if value in names}
    print(lst)
```

Comment: What you mean by pairs

Comment: Please clarify your task. Since your dict has consecutive indices, a list would be more appropriate. Indeed, a dict does not have ordering prior to python 3.7 and cannot be sliced.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output goes as follow: ['Hello','Bob','!', 'Hello','Bob','!','Hello','Jane','!']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dictionary is based on 3 value sequence, like 'Hello', then a name the '!' or '?' then the solution is quite simple. But first you must not assume order upon the dictionary. So I first convert it to a list of pairs and sort them:

```
>>> lst = sorted(d.items())
>>> lst
[(0, 'Hello'), (1, 'Bob'), (2, '!'), (3, 'Hello'), (4, 'Bob'), (5, '?'), (6, 'Hello'), (7, 'Bob'), (8, '!'), (9, 'Hello'), (10, 'Jane'), (11, '!'), (12, 'Hello'), (13, 'Rob'), (14, '?')]
```

Next, I need only the names. The indexes are implied:

```
>>> names = [name for num, name in lst]
>>> names
['Hello', 'Bob', '!', 'Hello', 'Bob', '?', 'Hello', 'Bob', '!', 'Hello', 'Jane', '!', 'Hello', 'Rob', '?']
```

Finally, extract the indexes you need:

```
>>> indexes = [i for i in range(0, len(names), 3) if names[i] == 'Hello' and names[i+2] == '!']
>>> indexes
[0, 6, 9]
```